# Moving files between build chain builds

Tags: teamcity

What is the set up required to move files between builds in TC? I am needing to move both modified source files and build binaries between the build configurations of a build chain.

I have 1 project with 4 builds. The builds are

1. Update Version Number (This build updates 15 sources files)
2. Compile (This build compiles a dozen objects)
3. Test (This build runs a regression test)
4. Create Package (This build creates a setup.exe file)

Information about the TC setup and chain

- I am using perforce as my VCS.
- All 4 builds use the same VCS root.
- On all 4 builds under version control settings I have "Clean all files before build" set to "On".
- "Update Version Number" build is triggered by any check in to the VCS. (This works)
- I have been able to successfully chain and trigger the builds. However each build starts with a fresh copy of files from the VCS.
- The chaining is set up to use snapshot dependency.

Based off of the [TC documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Dependencies+Setup) it looks like I should be using snapshot dependency and not artifact dependency. If I put the build steps of all the builds into the same build everything works. However we are looking to have more flexibly and expand on this build chain in the future.

I tried setting up the configuration so only the first build is attached to the VCS root and the other builds don't have any VCS root. This didn't work.

I have been unable to find the answer googling but I have been able to find [someone else who is struggling with this problem](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206853945-Chaining-builds-top-down). Sadly they didn't receive an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with TC customer support I learned the correct technique is to use both artifact dependency with "build from the same chain" selected and snapshot dependency.